# Why does `File::read_to_end` get slower the larger the buffer capacity?

Tags: windows, rust, io

***NOTICE:** As of 2023-04-23, a fix for this [landed on `rust-lang/rust:master`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/110655). You'll soon be able to use `File::read_to_end` without these worries.*

---

I was working on a pretty specific problem that required me to read hundreds of thousands of files ranging from a few bytes to a few hundred megabytes. As the bulk of the operation consisted in enumerating files and moving data from disk, I resorted to reusing `Vec` buffers for the file reading in hopes of avoiding some of that memory management.

That's when I hit the unexpected: `file.read_to_end(&mut buffer)?` gets progressively slower the larger the buffer's capacity is. It's a lot slower to read a 300MB file first followed by a thousand 1KB files than the other way around (as long as we don't truncate the buffer).

Confusingly, if I wrap the file in a `Take` or use `read_exact()`, no slowdown happens.

Does anyone know what that's about? Is it possible it (re)initializes the whole buffer every time it's called? Is this some Windows-specific quirk? What (Windows-based) profiling tools would you recommend when tackling something like this?

Here's a simple reproduction that demonstrates a *huge* (50x+ on this machine) performance difference between those methods, disk speeds disregarded:

```rust
use std::io::Read;
use std::fs::File;

// with a smaller buffer, there's basically no difference between the methods...
// const BUFFER_SIZE: usize = 2 * 1024;

// ...but the larger the Vec, the bigger the discrepancy.
// for simplicity's sake, let's assume this is a hard upper limit.
const BUFFER_SIZE: usize = 300 * 1024 * 1024;


fn naive() {
    let mut buffer = Vec::with_capacity(BUFFER_SIZE);

    for _ in 0..100 {
        let mut file = File::open("some_1kb_file.txt").expect("opening file");

        let metadata = file.metadata().expect("reading metadata");
        let len = metadata.len();
        assert!(len <= BUFFER_SIZE as u64);

        buffer.clear();
        file.read_to_end(&mut buffer).expect("reading file");

        // do "stuff" with buffer
        let check = buffer.iter().fold(0usize, |acc, x| acc.wrapping_add(*x as usize));

        println!("length: {len}, check: {check}");
    }
}

fn take() {
    let mut buffer = Vec::with_capacity(BUFFER_SIZE);

    for _ in 0..100 {
        let file = File::open("some_1kb_file.txt").expect("opening file");

        let metadata = file.metadata().expect("reading metadata");
        let len = metadata.len();
        assert!(len <= BUFFER_SIZE as u64);

        buffer.clear();
        file.take(len).read_to_end(&mut buffer).expect("reading file");

        // this also behaves like the straight `read_to_end` with a significant slowdown:
        // file.take(BUFFER_SIZE as u64).read_to_end(&mut buffer).expect("reading file");

        // do "stuff" with buffer
        let check = buffer.iter().fold(0usize, |acc, x| acc.wrapping_add(*x as usize));

        println!("length: {len}, check: {check}");
    }
}

fn exact() {
    let mut buffer = vec![0u8; BUFFER_SIZE];

    for _ in 0..100 {
        let mut file = File::open("some_1kb_file.txt").expect("opening file");

        let metadata = file.metadata().expect("reading metadata");
        let len = metadata.len() as usize;
        assert!(len <= BUFFER_SIZE);

        // SAFETY: initialized by `vec!` and within capacity by `assert!`
        unsafe { buffer.set_len(len); }
        file.read_exact(&mut buffer[0..len]).expect("reading file");

        // do "stuff" with buffer
        let check = buffer.iter().fold(0usize, |acc, x| acc.wrapping_add(*x as usize));

        println!("length: {len}, check: {check}");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = std::env::args().collect();

    if args.len() < 2 {
        println!("usage: {} <method>", args[0]);
        return;
    }

    match args[1].as_str() {
        "naive" => naive(),
        "take" => take(),
        "exact" => exact(),
        _ => println!("Unknown method: {}", args[1]),
    }
}
```

Tried in a few combinations of `--release` mode, `LTO` and even `+crt-static` to no significant difference.

Comment: I can't reproduce that on my machine. How are you measuring performance? What version of Rust are you using?

Comment: @SvenMarnach `rustc 1.68.2 (9eb3afe9e 2023-03-27)` with target `x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` on an up-to-date Windows 10 machine with VS22. With the example code, a `hyperfine 'binary naive' 'binary take' 'binary exact'` shows a 50x difference between them, regardless of order and warmup rounds. But even on my actual codebase the difference was enormous—so much so I started the investigation because it was immediately obvious something was wrong as IO went pretty fast _until_ the first large file, and after that every file took a lot longer to process.

Comment: Just pointing out that your usage of `unsafe` is UB. Guess it does not matter for the example.

Comment: But how are you _measuring_ it @ducktherapy - what tools are involved?  Or is this from running the .exe and it's so long it's obvious?  And in your example you just have a single 1k file.  Is that still all that's necessary to see the issue?  I'm at work so I can't try this right now or I would, as I'm on a similar environment.  Note that your `exact` case uses an array into the `vec!` macro which is different than your other two cases.  Hopefully doesn't have a large effect.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman That's indeed not a focus since it's just an example and I'd use the `Take` version _if I can't figure out the issue_, but as a sidenote, why's that? `Vec`'s docs just state the elements must be initialized and within capacity.

Comment: Uh sorry, I thought you're using `with_capacity()`. Yes, it is safe, but also unnecessary, because you can use `truncate()`.

Comment: Also, the code will panic on long lengths as `resize()` doesn't change the size, just the capacity.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Yes, the example code has such a difference on this machine that it's obvious even without measuring tools. However, the 50x figure came from running 'hyperfine' with the three methods. Both `exact` and `take` are 50x faster than `naive` and within margin of error of each other—the reason I initialized it with `vec!` for `exact` was because I used `set_len` and that requires the elements to be initialized. In my actual codebase I started with a small buffer and let it grow as files are read... and that's when the discrepancy showed up: larger file > larger buffer > slowdown.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Good catch. I should've picked better examples, but for simplicity's sake just assume `BUFFER_SIZE` is a known upper limit. `truncate()` right there would defeat the purpose of reusing the buffers. The reason I want to retain the buffers is because all the files easily fit within memory, but I might have to parse them randomly with regards to sizes: [100B, 100MB, 100KB, ...]. Instead of expanding/truncating the `Vec` over and over, I just want to hang onto a decently sized buffer. Actual project uses heuristics over a longer timeframe for memory reclamation.

Comment: ^Well, assuming `truncate()`'s `drop_in_place()` mean I'd need to reinit them. But I'm not sure on that—it should be fine to reuse `u8`s right? They're just opaque bits, no?

Comment: @ducktherapy - The way I see it, the _only_ difference between `naive` and `take` is literally `file.read_to_end` versus `file.take(len).read_to_end` - and here's [take](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.take).  Might there be some other optimization happening that makes that interact better with the later accumulator?  On the surface, I don't even know what made you _try_ `take` in the first place, as it doesn't seem like it'd make a difference, but I believe your account.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Believe me, I'm just as puzzled. The only reason I tried `Take` is because of a comment on the Rust forums from ages ago about eliminating preinitialization from `read_to_end`... But I'm sure it doesn't apply the same way anymore—there were multiple updates to these functions since. The fact they are both faster is still a mystery to me. Nothing jumped out in the std implementation code, but granted I didn't internalize the whole `read_to_end` -> `sys_impl` chain. Seems like I'll have to deep dive at some point, but it might as well just be some backend optimization failure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried using `take` with progressively higher numbers:

```rs
// Run with different values of `take` from 10_000_000 to 300_000_000
file.take(take)
    .read_to_end(&mut buffer)
    .expect("reading file");
```

And the runtime scaled with it almost exactly linearly.

[image: graph of time vs. take showing a linear correlation]

Using [`cargo flamegraph`](https://crates.io/crates/flamegraph) gives a clear picture: [`NtReadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/ntreadfile) takes 95% of the time.

[image: flamegraph of the executable]

It only takes 10% in the `exact` version. In other words, your rust code is not at fault.

The Windows docs don't suggest anything with respect to the length of the buffer, but from reading the rust standard library, it does appear that `NtReadFile` is given the entire spare capacity of the `Vec`, and it's apparent from the benchmark that `NtReadFile` is doing *something* on every byte in the buffer.

I believe the `exact` method would be best here. [`std::fs::read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read.html) also queries the length of the file before reading, although it always has a buffer of the right size since it creates the `Vec`. It also still uses `read_to_end` so that it returns a more correct file even if the length changed in between. If you want to reuse the `Vec`, you would need to do this some other way.

Make sure that whatever you choose is faster than recreating the `Vec` every time, which I tried a bit and got nearly the same performance as `exact`. There's performance benefits to freeing unused memory, so whether it makes your program faster will depend on the situation.

You could also separate the code paths for short and long files.

Finally, ensure you need the entire file. If you can do your processing with chunks of [`BufReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html) at a time, with [`fill_buf`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html#method.fill_buf) and [`consume`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html#method.consume), you can avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: Thank you for confirming I wasn't going crazy. In the test, recreating the `Vec` indeed makes little difference, but in the actual codebase keeping the buffer around is a clear winner, so I'll keep with `read_exact` then! Thank you!

Comment: Wait, I misread the graph, I thought it was `naive vs take`. Does this mean you observe both `naive` _and_ `take` to run linearly slower to buffer capacity, as opposed to `exact`? On my computer, only `naive` did it, the other two didn't. Yet another mystery.

Comment: @ducktherapy Yeah, I guess that isn't super clear. The numbers on the `take` axis is the u64 given as the argument to `take`.

Comment: I see—I redid it on my end and I'm seeing the same behavior with `take` now. I must've looked at the wrong thing when I ran `take(BUFFER_SIZE)`, so I'm relieved. Thanks again for the help.